# Getting message "Hmm… looks like this file doesn't have a preview we can show you" when trying to open a file from SharePoint or from MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-teams, teamsite

Getting message "Hmm… looks like this file doesn't have a preview we can show you" When I am trying to open a file from SharePoint or from teams. I have tried using teams client as well as online mode the file is not getting open in both the ways.

Note: This behavior is only observed for large files; the small file is getting opened.

PFA image.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us how you are opening the file?

Comment: I have added the attachment.

Comment: I get the sense that this question would be better asked on https://superuser.com/

Comment: We are mainly responsible for Microsoft Teams app development related issues.  

For Microsoft Teams product issues/failures your tenant Admin can reach out to [Microsoft 365 Product Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide&tabs=online).  

For general questions about Microsoft Teams please post your question on [Microsoft Teams Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum?sort=LastReplyDate&dir=Desc&tab=All&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&isFilterExpanded=false&page=1).